# show hide animation in angular using css

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, css-animations

In angular I want to show/hide a div , I have done it using `ng-if` but I want animation effect on opening and closing of div. And I want to use css for that. Any help would be great.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/87mwvq7p/1/

```
<button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">Toggle!</button>

<div class="box on" ng-show="toggle" ng-animate="'box'">On</div>
<div class="box off" ng-hide="toggle" ng-animate="'box'">Off</div>
```

Have a look at the above example..it might help you

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question. Here's the solution:

The HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv">test </button>
  <div ng-class="{ 'vis': showDiv}" >
   hello test
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.vis {
   opacity:0;
   transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

The Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

}
```

Hope it helps!!